# Mysql Auto increment goest 10 by 10

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

I have a **MySQL** table with an auto increment id declared as follows:

```
create table bases(
    idBase int primary key auto increment,
    nombreBase varchar(50) not null
)
```

When I insert two records:

```
insert into bases values('Base 1');
insert into bases values('Base 2');
```

It should go with id 1 and then 2, but it goes 1 and then 11, if I `insert` a third takes 21.  Is there any particular reason why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT!!!!**

Solved thanks to the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206751/mysql-autoincrement-column-jumps-by-10-why)

Comment: Try running SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';  If auto_increment_increment is not 1 then that could be your answer

Comment: I solved thanks to what answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206751/mysql-autoincrement-column-jumps-by-10-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN my search I found some things to help you on your way

1. [Auto skipping numbers-question asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798835/auto-increment-skipping-numbers)
2. [Insert-Ignore tutorial](https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/11/29/avoiding-auto-increment-holes-on-innodb-with-insert-ignore/)

**Explicitly: Try running this in your db manager**

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
```

Comment: the autoinc value is set to 10