# In MySql I do not want Missing ID when Inserting New Row

Tags: mysql

My Current Table: (**id** is auto increament)

`id  |  name
  1   |  spain
  2   |  canada
  4   |  england
  6   |  russia
  7   |  Brazil
  9   |  Italy`

ID: 3,5,8 Miss

i want when inserting new row , new row insert to `row id 3` after `row id 5` and then `row id 8`.

but when i insert new row, cause to `10 | germany`.!!!

Comment: See [Auto Increment skipping numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798835/auto-increment-skipping-numbers). This will usually happen when you use statements like `insert ignore`, `insert ... on duplicate key ...` or similar stuff. You can manually use id 3, 5, and 8 as an id for your next inserts, mysql will not autofill it for you. If you deleted it yourself, then never reuse this id.

Comment: its not http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto-increment columns in RDBMS systems don't re-use numbers from rows that have been deleted.  If you want functionality as you have described, then you have to turn off auto-increment in the column, and your program will have to figure out how to insert in the way you're describing.  It's a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) specifies the following:

> When you insert any other value into an AUTO_INCREMENT column, the **column is set to that value** and the sequence is reset so that the next automatically generated value follows sequentially from the largest column value.

Can you provide the text of your insert statement?

Comment: No, my table is auto insert and delete from users. (such as likes posts users tables)