# Auto increment id field is not add 1 after executing MySQL bulk insert query

Tags: mysql

While testing the user table I made, I found something strange.
When adding a single row after executing a query that bulk inserts multiple users as shown below, the value of the id field increases by 2 instead of 1.

**bulk insert query**

```
INSERT INTO USER_TB (ID,NICKNAME,USER_LV,EXP) VALUES (1,'test1',1,0)
,(NULL,'test2',1,0)
,(NULL,'test3',1,0)
,(NULL,'test4',1,0);
```

**single row insert query**

```
INSERT INTO USER_TB (ID,NICKNAME,USER_LV,EXP) VALUES (NULL,'test5',1,0);
```

**Expected Result**

[image: I expected the look of the following table.]

**actual result**

[image: But I had to look at the following table.]

It works fine if you don't force the id field in bulk insert query.
But I want to know why this is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not reproducable see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=99fafb72558560d2656d5751f66a084e as long as you don't delete rows, it should give you always the nex number, hwat could happne, ist that the "order" could get messup

Comment: Sorry, but could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problme, see fiddle, so in my experience skips doesn't happen, without user action like **removing** a row. of course when you have an heavy duty server with lots and lots of traffic and different entitys mysql or processor, can rearrange code, i could think of a psoobilty that a number has skiped, but a bulk insert isn't a reason. that said, as i mentioned that there are entitys that can rearrange code, it can happen that test1 is after test 3 even with a sequential number.

Comment: I reproduced the problem in your fiddle. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=66fb8d1aff6b47d2394ece5e4256807d

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17798835/auto-increment-skipping-numbers

Comment: thx your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually quite tricky

> ```
> CREATE TABLE USER_TB (ID INT Auto_inCREMENT Primary KEY,
> NICKNAME varchar(50)
> ,USER_LV INT ,
> EXP BIGINT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO USER_TB (ID,NICKNAME,USER_LV,EXP) VALUES (NULL,'test1',1,0),(NULL,'test2',1,0),(NULL,'test3',1,0),(NULL,'test4',1,0),
> (NULL,'test5',1,0),(NULL,'test6',1,0),(NULL,'test7',1,0),(NULL,'test8',1,0),
> (NULL,'test9',1,0),(NULL,'test10',1,0),(NULL,'test11',1,0),(NULL,'test12',1,0);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
> ```
>
> ```
> | LAST_INSERT_ID() |
> | ---------------: |
> |                1 |
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO USER_TB VALUES (NULL,'test13',1,0),(NULL,'test14',1,0)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
> ```
>
> ```
> | LAST_INSERT_ID() |
> | ---------------: |
> |               13 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM USER_TB;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | NICKNAME | USER_LV | EXP
> -: | :------- | ------: | --:
>  1 | test1    |       1 |   0
>  2 | test2    |       1 |   0
>  3 | test3    |       1 |   0
>  4 | test4    |       1 |   0
>  5 | test5    |       1 |   0
>  6 | test6    |       1 |   0
>  7 | test7    |       1 |   0
>  8 | test8    |       1 |   0
>  9 | test9    |       1 |   0
> 10 | test10   |       1 |   0
> 11 | test11   |       1 |   0
> 12 | test12   |       1 |   0
> 13 | test13   |       1 |   0
> 14 | test14   |       1 |   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=714a8c9f2e5f577c8315c14ce57ce0f3)*

What your insert has differnet is the first

```
(1,'test1',1,0)
```

and so mysql counts **+1** so it seems like it skipped 1 number

If i put as first insert

```
(2,'test1',1,0)
```

It starts at 2 and "skips" also 2 at the end of the first INSERT, because in his internal counter he has 14 (12 + 2)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE USER_TB (ID INT Auto_inCREMENT Primary KEY,
> NICKNAME varchar(50)
> ,USER_LV INT ,
> EXP BIGINT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO USER_TB (ID,NICKNAME,USER_LV,EXP) VALUES (2,'test1',1,0),(NULL,'test2',1,0),(NULL,'test3',1,0),(NULL,'test4',1,0),
> (NULL,'test5',1,0),(NULL,'test6',1,0),(NULL,'test7',1,0),(NULL,'test8',1,0),
> (NULL,'test9',1,0),(NULL,'test10',1,0),(NULL,'test11',1,0),(NULL,'test12',1,0);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
> ```
>
> ```
> | LAST_INSERT_ID() |
> | ---------------: |
> |                3 |
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO USER_TB VALUES (NULL,'test13',1,0),(NULL,'test14',1,0)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
> ```
>
> ```
> | LAST_INSERT_ID() |
> | ---------------: |
> |               15 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM USER_TB;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | NICKNAME | USER_LV | EXP
> -: | :------- | ------: | --:
>  2 | test1    |       1 |   0
>  3 | test2    |       1 |   0
>  4 | test3    |       1 |   0
>  5 | test4    |       1 |   0
>  6 | test5    |       1 |   0
>  7 | test6    |       1 |   0
>  8 | test7    |       1 |   0
>  9 | test8    |       1 |   0
> 10 | test9    |       1 |   0
> 11 | test10   |       1 |   0
> 12 | test11   |       1 |   0
> 13 | test12   |       1 |   0
> 15 | test13   |       1 |   0
> 16 | test14   |       1 |   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ec38fd8b5a620d94ecd5efeede7c096a)*

so start with `(NULL,'test1',1,0)` and everything works as expected

Comment: Is the auto increment value determined by the internal counter value? and What is the relationship between Internal counter and LAST_INSERT_ID?